# How to Add a Row of Values from One DF to Another

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through the table, and copy/append a row to another table based on its' column value. So if the value in the 3rd column is -1, the entire row is copied to another table (t_neg1).

```
cluster_table = clusters
table                        = [cluster_table, Label]
cluster_table                = pd.concat(table,  axis = 1, sort = False)
col                          = list(["X", "Y", "Cluster ID"])

# This part below here is causing me issues.
t_neg1 = pd.DataFrame()
t_0    = pd.DataFrame()

# I'm sures there's a better way to handle this but I'll look into it later
i = 0
for i in range(len(cluster_table)):
    if cluster_table['Cluster ID'].loc == -1:
        t_neg1.copy(cluster_table.loc[i])
    if cluster_table['Cluster ID'].loc == 0:
        t_0.copy(cluster_table.loc[i])


        i += 1

print(t_neg1)
```

Can someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A column of what? How are you manipulating that data? Always share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. It's a bad idea to name variables `min` and `max`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete but still it looks like you are looking for this:

```
for n, i in enumerate(fcma):
    value = (i - min) / (max - min)
    fcma[n] =value
```

Answer (score 0):

value = (i - min) / (max - min)

Here min & max are 'builtin_function_or_method' not values(int/float/double). Hence  operation '-' has wrong operands of wrong types.

According to your need at hand, first assign values to min & max, then you can use as is.
 to

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is no builtin data type `column`, so you should give us an example.

As the error message suggests, you are are doing something `wrong` with Python builtins.

`min` and `max` are Python functions - you cannot add or subtract them.

While it is possible to redeclare `min` and `max`, please do not do this - as exactly these kind of errors can happen.

If you cannot find a better name, please use `min_` and `max_` - appending an underscore to prevent shadowing builtins is common Python practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `min` and `max`as variable names but they are Built-in functions.
Try to rename your's variables.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-min-python/